# IE: Blocked website from displaying content with security certificate errors

Tags: security, internet-explorer, certificate, blocked

A website my company develops has a security certificate error in IE(8)
It can be found here: www.fonq.nl

Anyone having similar problems and a solution?

Comment: That site doesn't seem to be supporting https. When does the error occur?

Comment: On which port is HTTPS enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Google Certificate issue

Certificate error message at the bottom of the screen:
"Internet Explorer blocked this website from displaying content with security certificate errors"

The error message appears when accessing Google (Gmail, Google Calendar, Google browser)
The error message only appears in Internet Explorer 10 --- not with Firefox, Safari, Netscape

Note:  "www.google.com" appears at the bottom of the "Untrusted Publishers" list (Tools-Internet Options-Content-Certificates-Untrusted Publishers) and cannot be edited or removed.  The intended purpose of this certificate is for server and client authentication.

Measures I have already taken to eliminate the message, but without success:
1.  Re-set the date and time (5 times)
2.  Ran a full system scan w/ Microsoft Security Essentials (twice)
3.  Ran a full system scan with Ace Utilities [including registry clean] (3 times)
4.  Removed and reinstalled Internet Explorer (twice)
5.  Disabled all add-ons and extensions
6.  Placed Google URLs in the list of "trusted sites" (Tools-Internet Options-Security-Trusted Sites)
7.  Unchecked (Tools-Internet Options-Advanced-Security) "Check for Publishers' Certificate Revocation"
8.  Unchecked (Tools-Internet Options-Advanced-Security) "Check for Server Certificate Revocation"
9.  Unchecked (Tools-Internet Options-Advanced-Security) "Check for Signatures on Downloaded Programs"

What finally worked:  Unchecked (Tools-Internet Options-Advanced-Security) "Warn about certificate address mismatch*"

Comment: Does this apply to IE8 as well?